# Understanding issue get one row from database with 2 parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3

I thought it would work find, but it doesn't.

I have a method in my modelclass like this:

```
public function getUnitbyName2($unitname, $ProjectID)
    {
        //$id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['Unitname' => $unitname], ['ProjectID' => $ProjectID]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) {
//          throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
//                  'Could not find row with identifier %d',
//                  $unitname
//                  ));
            $row=0;
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

If I give an existing unitname and a non existent project_ID I expect to get some 0 value. But I always get the number of the unit in the first project with the given unitname. It is common that the unitname exists in several different projects. 
The function is supposed to get the right record if exist using both parameters.

My question is, what's wrong with using 2 parameters connected by AND?

Answer (score 0):

**[AbstractTableGateway::select()](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/3.0.0/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php#L182)** accepts one argument, you are passing 2:
You need to pass 1, combine the 2 arrays.
Change your code to:

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['Unitname' => $unitname, 'ProjectID' => $ProjectID]);
```

- [Zend table Gateways](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-db/table-gateway/#table-gateways)